# exec: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm storing code snippets inside the Postgres DB. When I need the code, I find it inside the DB and use `exec()` function. The code snippet is a body of `extract` function.

Unfortunately it returns `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

**Method**

```
def extract(self,response):
    exec(self.custom_code)
```

**Code snippet** (repr(code_snippet))

```
u"return response.xpath('/text()')"
```

I suppose that it should behave like this:

```
def extract(self,response):
    return response.xpath('/text()')
```

What I should do?
This is just one line snippet and I need to execute multiline snippets.

**EDIT:**

I'm using Django with PostgreSQL and I realised that it strips spaces at the beginning of the line - indentation. I don't know if it has to do something with the problem.

**EDIT2:**

Tried eval instead of exec. Now it raises:

```
  File "/home/milano/PycharmProjects/Stilio_project/stilio/engine/models.py", line 107, in extract
    eval(self.custom_code)
  File "<string>", line 1
    return response.xpath('/text()')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: could you do `return eval(self.custom_code)`?

Comment: I tried it and it returns invalid syntax error, I've added error at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik, don't put a `return` inside the string when you're using `eval`.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik: I think the suggestion was to store `u"response.xpath('/text()')"` instead of `u"return response.xpath('/text()')"`, so you could move the `return` outside the `eval`/`exec`-ed code.

Comment: (that said, with my security hat on, storing code in a database (except where it's effectively sandboxed at runtime, which Python doesn't support) is a horrid, *horrid* idea -- it means any breach of your datastore is also a breach of your app servers. It also means that said code can't be byte-compiled ahead-of-time, and that even if you switch to an interpreter that supports JIT optimizations such as PyPy, you won't get the benefit of them, so you're taking a performance penalty as well).

Comment: Why are you storing code in db?  Don't do that.

Comment: If I put return outside the string, it works but I need eval multiline snippets sometimes.

Comment: I parse prices from thousands of urls. Every url can have different parsing technique. For 99% urls, there is just one tag so I can set parsing and xpath using attributes. But sometimes you need to find element and extract text from multiple tags inside it and replace something etc. so I decided that this could be the best option to be able to dynamically setting parser.

Comment: Well, you decided wrong.  Database is for *data*, not logic.  So find the essence of the data (e.g. urls, tags) that differs for each different parsing technique, and just store/retrieve that.  You won't have to deal with these crazy syntax errors and scoping issues.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik: You'd be surprised how much you can do in a single expression; if you absolutely must do this, you might have to go through some contortions to rewrite statements or blocks into expressions, but it can almost always be done.

Comment: I suggest to build multiple parsers for each domain and do some OOP for the 1% where you need an special solution - instead of doing evals. Just a note from my personal experience: When your process of extracting/scraping data will be more and more complicated, _one codebase_ (for everything) will be very hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the `exec` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec):

> Be aware that the `return` and `yield` statements may not be used outside of function definitions even within the context of code passed to the `exec` statement.

So `exec` is explicitly off-limits. And that wording is global, not specific to `exec`; on checking, while `eval` using code `compile`-ed in `'single'` mode has the same error; you can't dynamically insert `return` statements like this.

If you absolutely must allow executing arbitrary code, I strongly recommend limiting it to expressions, not statements, and implicitly returning the result of said expressions. So instead of storing `u"return response.xpath('/text()')"`, you'd store `u"response.xpath('/text()')"`, and your code that performs dynamic invocation would change to:

```
def extract(self,response):
    return eval(self.custom_code)
```